# Change the actual (or viewable) Wordpress directory structure

Tags: php, htaccess, directory

I like the simplicity of wordpress and all it has to offer, but for security purposes I would like to change the actual (or viewable) directory structure of my site.

The install has a set of files that everybody who's familiar with wordpress will know about. I have read about some security measures some where that suggests changing the file/directory structure of a wordpress site to increase the level of security. This would prevent someone from knowing right away if a site wordpress based or not.

I have no idea how to do this, but I think using the htaccess might be a solution. Im also concerned about future updates and is there a way to change the actual (or viewable) file structure without effecting updates.

I would appreciate some advice on this. Thanks for any help on the matter!

Comment: Changing names is **not** a security feature. We discuss this each week again …

Comment: @toscho, I dont want to change names I want to change the directory structure. Maybe by moving the wp-admin, wp-content, and wp-includes somewhere else but to in a way not to cause any problems with how wordpress operates...

Comment: Our search engine offers some answers to your question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=rename+directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been answered many times. Search this site, as toscho points out above.

And see [Ben Word - Hide WordPress](http://benword.com/), who shows how to:

> 1 - Clean up the output of wp_head and removing the generator from
>   RSS feeds
>
> 2 - Hide /wp-content/ by rewriting static theme assets (CSS, JS, and
>   images), rewriting the plugins directory, and also changing the
>   location of WordPress uploads
>
> 3 - Clean up the output of navigation menus with a custom walker
>
> 4 - Show root relative URLs